# Как реактивно подключить полученный через ajax html в Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

Я получил html через ajax, записал его в переменную vue и вывел на странице через `v-html`, но там где была кнопка с событием, вместо события, так и осталось `v-on:click`
[image]

Я подумал и пришёл к выводу, что Vue.js при создании экземпляра класса `Vue` проходит весь DOM и компилирует - заменяет все `{{...}}`, `v-on` и прочее. Но как же тогда мне подключить html, при этом что бы оно его откомпилировало?

На всякий случай вот код: [тык](https://filebin.net/5twtsxt9xgsfjd2n)

Comment: Никак. А вообще, это очень плохая практика - брать html с апишки. Оттуда надо брать данные, скалывать их в Vuex, а потом в компоненте отрисовывать.

Comment: @АлександрРогонов спасибо, приму во внимание.